# Color Accent of Android 5.0 not working on pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I have implemented the color accent for my app in android but somehow that is not reflected properly in pre lollipop devices the tabs highlighted bar stays blue even in some views edittextview selected also stays blue while at some other place it implements coloraccent.

here is my styles xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Please help me out with it.

Following is my Gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.karmadigi.bombaycasting.bombaycasting"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

Following is my Styles xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

v19 styles code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

v21 styles code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I only have default values and v19 & v21 styles file in project.

Comment: Are you using any custom views where those colours don't work?

Comment: no not using any custom views, only using tabhost with widget and inbuilt edittextview and other inbuilt views only. If you need anyspecific code please let me know. will post it.

Comment: Are you using support library 22.2 or later?

Comment: You should use TabLayout from material design library instead of TabHost. Are you sure the activities displaying those edit texts where colors don't work aren't using a different theme?

Comment: Your Activities inherit from AppCompatActivity or a appropriate Delegate?

Comment: I am using AppCompatActivity but my tabhost selected tabs still show in holo blue color on pre lollipop devices.

Comment: Put common theme attrs in AppTheme not AppTheme.Base. You have different bases for different API levels but one final theme.

Comment: @EugenPechanec please elaborate i have uploaded my styles xml there are 2 more styles xml for values-v19 & values-v21 should i also put in question

Comment: Yes, you can. There should be an `AppTheme.Base` style in each of them. This style contains platform specific settings. On this theme is based the `AppTheme` style. There should be only one in `values`. This style contains common attributes such as `colorPrimary` etc. so it gets applied on all platforms.

Comment: @EugenPechanec please check i have updated question

Comment: Remove common attrs from AppTheme.Base style (also meaning you don't need special v19 styles at all). **|||** Make sure that you inflate everything using **activity context**. `setContentView` does that for you. When you inflate manually use `LayoutInflater.from(this)` in activity or `LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())` in fragments. If you create widgets via constructor make sure you use AppCompat prefixed ones (instead of `new EditText(...)` you need to use `new AppCompatEditText(...)`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec i bymistakely extended one class to Activity which i changed to AppCompatActivity so now the Edit text is taking color accent in prelollipop devices but the tabhost selected tab is not taking the coloraccent color.

and by your above reply i should remove style file from v19 and i use getactivity in layoutinflator only and i have not used appcompatedittext but simple edittext but its using coloraccent in prelollipop issue is with tabhost only

Comment: You keep saying TabHost. You want [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

Comment: @EugenPechanec ok i am new to material design stuff so i was under impression of tabhost as i used earlier but now came to know that its deprecated. Will implement tablayout and get back to you. but that will take some time as i have to 1st complete flow of application as i am on short deadline. Thank you for help mate

Comment: @NiranjanBalkrishnaPrajapati i am facing same sort of issue, did you got solution for this?